# How is reachability reduced to order maintenance?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

After reading [Dimitris Andreou's blog post on reachability](http://code-o-matic.blogspot.com/2010/07/graph-reachability-transitive-closures.html), it seems that [reachability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability) can be reduced to [order-maintenance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-maintenance_problem). A solution to the order-maintenance problem has the following interface:

1. Insert (X, Y ): Insert a new element Y immediately after element X in the
   total order.
2. Delete (X): Remove an element X from the total order.
3. Order (X, Y ): Determine whether X precedes Y in the total order.

The reachability problem is easily solved by just calling `Order(X, Y)` to check if `Y` is reachable from `X`, but I'm not sure how this works with non-tree DAGs. For example, what if you have a graph like this (from the [Multiple inheritance diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem)):

[image]

and you'd like to answer queries like: "Does D inherit from A?" (is A reachable from D). You'd have to call `Insert(D, B)`, `Insert(D, C)`, `Insert(B, A)`, `Insert(C, A)`, and then `Order(D, A)`. However, AFAIK, the `Insert(X, Y)` method can only be called if `Y` does not already exist, so this wouldn't work with vertex `A`.

How can you solve reachability for non-tree DAGs using order-maintenance?